# How to find how many bytes of data array holding

Tags: perl

How to find how many bytes of data array holding?
@aead=("ansfl;ahslhfalkhf aklshfakl;");

I find the array how many bytes of data it has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Devel::Size](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aSize) has tools to measure memory usage.

```
use Devel::Size qw( total_size );
my $memory_usage = total_size(\@a);
```

If you are really trying to find the total of the number of characters in each string in the array,

```
use List::Util qw( sum );
my $total = sum 0, map length, @a;
```

or

```
my $total = 0;
$total += length for @a;
```